# Отправка email (java)

Tags: java, email

Я пытаюсь отправить email с помощью следующего кода:

```
  try {
        String mailFrom = "sender@mail.ru";
        String pass = "pass";
        String mailTo = "recipient@gmail.com";

        java.util.Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.ru");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "60000"); // 60 seconds
        props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "60000");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return (new PasswordAuthentication(mailFrom, pass));
            }
        });
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(mailFrom);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
        InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress(mailTo);
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        msg.setSubject("testemail");
        Transport.send(msg);
   } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("Exception : " + e.toString());
   }
```

но получаю ошибку:

> Exception : javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to
>   TLS;
>   nested exception is:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

При этом я добавила ssl-сертификат mail.ru в хранилище сертификатов JVM, и он был успешно добавлен.

Если же я добавляю в сессию следующее свойство:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
```

то по прошествии минуты (по истечении установленного таймаута) получаю другую ошибку:

> Exception : javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
>   nested exception is:  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Как исправить это и всё-таки отправить email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я пыталась отправить пустое сообщение, без тела (почтовый клиент обычно разрешает посылать такие сообщения, но в моём случае это привело к ошибке).

Это выяснилось после того, как я добавила в сессию свойство

`props.put("mail.debug", "true");`

После этого в отладочной информации я увидела причину ошибки:

> 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
>
> DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW:
>
> javax.mail.MessagingException: No MimeMessage content

После получения этого описания ошибки я добавила тело сообщения:

```
msg.setText("Test message!");
```

и email был успешно отправлен.